# IFormattable.ToString not working as expected for Hexadecimal formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, hex, string-formatting

String.Format and IFormattable.ToString(format, value) provides different result when trying to format to hexadecimal. How to get correct results when using IFormattable.ToString(format, value)

```
string format = "0x{0:X4}";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(format, 255)); //prints- 0x00FF

IFormattable formattableValue = (IFormattable)255;
Console.WriteLine(formattableValue.ToString(format, null)); //prints- 25x{5:X4}
```

Answer (score 2):

The format of the formatting string is different for `string.Format()` and for `ToString()`. In particular, `string.Format()` allows for other text around the format, while `IFormattable.ToString()` only allows the format specifier for the text itself.

In your example, the format string `"0x{0:X4}"` is being treated as the whole format specifier for the value 255. The `0` are placeholders for digits, and the rest is just extra character literals.

If you want `IFormattable.ToString()` to output the same as `string.Format()` you have to use it in an equivalent way:

```
"0x" + formattableValue.ToString("X4", null);
```