# IFormattable returns wrong value while using format

Tags: c#, hex, type-conversion, iformattable

I have tried to format a value in HexaDeciamal format using IFormattable, and String.Format. But both return different values. Please suggest some format to get the value like String.Format.
Code :

```
Console.WriteLine("\nValue :  \t" + string.Format(format, 255));

Result is : "0x00FF" 
object obj = 255;
IFormattable formattableValue = (IFormattable)obj;
string value = formattableValue.ToString(format, null);

Console.WriteLine("\nValue :  \t" + value); 

Result : "25x{5:X4}"
```

Please let me know if you have any concerns.

[Click Here for sample](https://syncfusion.atlassian.net/wiki/download/attachments/68223089/Sample.zip?version=1&modificationDate=1447763269182&api=v2)

Comment: sounds like a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771524/iformattable-tostring-not-working-as-expected-for-hexadecimal-formatting

Comment: What is the value of `format`, `formattableValue`, `value`? Show the whole code block.

Comment: value of formattablevalue is  255;

Comment: If `format` is `"0x{0:X4}"`  then when you call `string.Format` it's going to call `ToString("X4", someFormatProvider)` not `ToString("0x{0:X4}", someFormatProvider)`, that's the difference.  So the equivalent would be `"0x"  + formattableValue.ToString("X4", null)`.